# Protect downloads on remote server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 servers. On Server 1 I have a WordPress website. On Server 2 I have large .zip files that I want members from the WordPress site to be able to download.

How do I authenticate these users so that only people that are members of the website can download files from the second server?

Is it possible to use PHP so that only referrers from my domain have access to the files?

Note: The links to download the files are protected on the wordpress site so that non-logged in users are redirected to a join page. However, current and ex-members would still know the directory where the downloads are and could possibly download the files or share the links.

Comment: Beware about using tokens based in current timestamp. How many thing can happen at the same time, it is really a very bad idea to use tokens based in time, unless you have some prefix in that string and it must be unique. Try something with unique IDs generated by your database, it is totally safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this. The most secure way would be to have some back-end communication between Server 1 & Server 2. But here is an easy alternative:

**Server 2 : download.php**

```
<?PHP
 $file = $_GET['f'];
 $code = $_GET['c']; 
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

 if ($code != md5($ip . 'salt')) {
    die('authentication denied');
 }

 if(!file)
 {
     die('file not found');
 }

 // Set headers
 header("Cache-Control: public");
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
 header("Content-Type: application/zip");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

 // Read the file from disk
 readfile('/files/downloads/' . $file);

?>
```

**Server 1 : Download link**

```
<?PHP
 echo '<a href="http://server2.com/download.php?f=text.txt&c=' . md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . 'salt') / '">Download File</a>';
?>
```

This system works by creating a link that can only be used on the IP it was generated for. So a registered user cannot share the link elsewhere. It's not the most secure thing but it's easy to implement and will work.

Comment: Thank you for the response! For the server 2 code, that would need to be placed on a domain, or can just upload it directly to the server's IP? I also assume that the "Read the file from disk" section - I would want the files to be located in the readfile('my/download/path/here' directory?

Comment: The code for server2 just needs to be publicly accessible. And yes change "/files/downloads/" to fit your needs. Please mark answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Some neat solution may be to use a token system based on current time. You can take current hour of the day and hash it with some salt, and put it in the query string as token. Than php script on second server may check if query-string hash is same, as hash generated for current hour of the day with same salt on server side.

To be sure that user won't hit the hour-switch time you can check for previous hour hash too.

It makes you certain that file url won't be available for more than two hours with guaranteed time of availability of one hour.

On server 1:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="server2.com/download.php?token='.md5(date('G')+'secret_word').'&file=file.zip">Link</a>';
?>
```

On server 2:

```
<?php
current_hour_hash = md5( date('G').'secret_word' );
previous_hour_number = ( int(date('G')) - 1 ) % 24;
previous_hour_hash = md5( str(previous_hour_number).'secret_word' );
if($_GET['token']!= current_hour_hash and $_GET['token']!= previous_hour_hash){
    die();
}else{
    ... //code sending file here
}
```